# Get rid of the timestamp in Eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to get rid of the timestamp in Eclipse console?

[image]

I am recording screencasts and don't want to show the date/time within my videos.

Comment: can you just take out the console window and then resize it to not show the timestamp

Answer (score 1):

no, there isn't any way to do that.However, you can try to hide it somewhat by dragging the console to top-right.The timestamp is still there but in order to see it, you have to swipe right.

as shown,

[image]

if it is still visible, you can decrease the size of console.

Still, this is not the exact solution to your question.
I hope this might helps a little.